# Checking if input is correct data type in C#

Tags: c#

What I would like is to basically have the user enter in a float, and then the system check that the input is indeed a float, and if it is then it will proceed with the code, and if it is not then the user will have to re-input the with the correct data type.
Sorry for the beginners question, an example of the code is:

```
            Console.Write("Response Value > ");
            Response = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

            Ask_Count = Ask_Count + 1;
            if (Response > 0 && Response < 6)
            {
                Valid_Count = Valid_Count + 1;
            }
```

How would I go about the program checking to see if Response is a float?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another is by using `is float`.

```
bool result = varName is float;
```

or

```
float x = 0;
bool result = float.tryParse(varname, out x);
```

Comment: Not for this particular scenario. `Console.ReadLine()` will always return a `string`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `float.TryParse` for it.

```
Console.Write("Response Value > ");
if(float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Response)
{
    Ask_Count = Ask_Count + 1;
    if (Response > 0 && Response < 6)
        Valid_Count = Valid_Count + 1;
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Number entered is not a float");
```

Comment: While correct, perhaps it would be more useful if you included a link to MSDN and/or showed how this would integrate with the current code? Just giving a method name isn't really an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderR: I was writing it. check out.